# Inject existing object into asp.net web api 2 controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, owin

I want to send data from an existing project over HTTP. To do that I decided to use OWIN to self-host a web server from that particular project (I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api), not sure this is the best way though). This existing project has some objects that need to serve as a model for the controller's web API. My problem is that I don't know how to pass an existing object to a controller. Dependency injection seems to only allow me to create new objects, furthermore the object is only available at the point where I start the web app. Here is the code

```
private void Initialize()
{
    // TODO: this object needs to somehow end up in the controllers.
    CustomObject object = base.object;
    _webApp = WebApp.Start(baseAddress, Startup);
}

private void Startup(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    // Configure Web API for self-host.
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "REST API",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
    config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new MyAssembliesResolver());

    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
}

public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // TODO: so this needs to be filled in with the object from the Initialize() method above.
    private CustomObject _customObject; 

    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> GetAll()
    {
        // I want to use this customObject to send information about the project that is actually hosting the web api.
        // return _customObject.Data;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Dependency injection seems to only allow me to create new objects"_ - No, dependency injection allows you to inject objects in accordance with the lifetime you set for them. Why don't you register `CustomObject` with the container?

Comment: Of course... First I was using the Start<TStartup>(String) version so I couldn't see how to get that object into the Startup class as they use in the tutorial. But if I just use Start(String, Action<IAppBuilder>) then I can of course use a private method that can access the object. Thanks!